# Center the bars in Funnel chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to make funnel chart in R. As an example I took code from this page https://analyzecore.com/2015/06/23/sales-funnel-visualization-with-r/
But the strange thing is, which I could not get, why my bars are skewed to the left side?

```
Funnel data: 

       Category Number
1 total_members   1000
2  paid_members    936
3 cancellations    452
4       refunds     34

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols)+
  geom_bar(data=funnel_data, aes(x=Category, y=Number, fill=Category), stat="identity", width=1)
```

Results in

[image]

If you just run the piece of code from the article, this one for example:

```
ggplot() +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols) +
  geom_bar(data=df.all, aes(x=step, y=number, fill=content), stat="identity", width=1)
```

It will give you a nice example with bars centered by X:
[image]

I have no clue what is the issue in this case. Would be very glad for any assisance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is different approach, but works - create second `geom_bar` geom with negative values:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Using OPs data
ggplot(funnel_data, aes(Category, fill = Category)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y =  Number), stat = "identity", width = 1) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = -Number), stat = "identity", width = 1) +
    theme_minimal() +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: @ФанкиДжаз happy to help